# Gala consuming a ton of memory with Nvidia Optimus

Tags: gala

Gala is using 9.5 GB of memory. This is after running for about 2 days. There is obviously some kind of memory leak. Is this known and is there any work being done on it?

Answer (score 1):

Known: Yes, Fixed: Seem Not Yet as there is a bug report still open.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/gala/+bug/1488183

You can register in launchpad and flag that bug as it does affect you. So it will get more light.

Seems there is some other users facing same bug:

- [Reddit: Gala high memory usage *temporary* workaround](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/2pyn3d/gala_high_memory_usage_temporary_workaround/)
- [Google+: Anyone else experiencing a slow memory leak in gala?](https://plus.google.com/+RellonLawrence/posts/Z1iT5bgyk6N)﻿